# Referencing F# From C# Windows Phone XNA game project

Tags: c#, dll, f#, xna

i'm quite new to this, i'm currently working on a project for university which involves having to create a Windows Phone Xna Game in both C# and F#. I've been trying for a while now link the F# to the C# project, for instance creating a variable in the F# project that I can use in the C#. I want to use F# to do some of the calculations for the C# Game. However i'm really struggling to link these two projects, i've tried adding the projects into the same solution, i've tried using an F# C# template but it won't seem to pick up the F# project. I have read from looking through questions on here to use a dll from the F# project and reference it in the C# project however i'm still unsure how to do this after reading up lots. Could anyone tell me how I could get an integer value from a F# project to use in the C# or how I can use/create this dll to do it on Windows Phone XNA? I have tried to research but am getting nowhere, Thanks.

Comment: Have you right clicked the C# project and done 'add reference' and selected the F# project from the solution?

Comment: Why would you want to take an integer value from F# to C#?  Surely you want to get the result of a calculation back from F# to C# right?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an F# project in your C# project's solution
2. In your C# project, right-click References and select Add
   Reference...
3. From the Project tab, select your F# project.

You should now be able to use your F# project's *public* types within your C# project. For example, if you created a type using "type public" in F#, you'll be able to instantiate it and call its static methods if any.